# libc++abi.dylib dyld error after updating xcode to 5.0

Tags: xcode, xcode5, dyld, libc++

After updating XCode to 5.0 (in Mac OS X 10.8) I have encountered following issue:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x7fff5fc0109c:  int3   
0x7fff5fc0109d:  nop
```

with debug message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZdlPv
  Referenced from: /Users/JohnSmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServerCV-eoytszzoivnjodejdhsvdkjgznlj/Build/Products/Debug/ServerCV
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
 in /Users/JohnSmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServerCV-eoytszzoivnjodejdhsvdkjgznlj/Build/Products/Debug/ServerCV
(lldb)
```

before the xcode upgrade it worked fine.

Comment: I got the same error on ios 6.  but my app runs on ios 7.  Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: Yes, my solution is below, in a separate answer. But I was running MacOsX, not iOS, so I'm not sure if it will help in iOS. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing the following setting in the project settings:

```
Architectures>>
>> Base SDK >>
>> Latest OS X (OS X 10.9)
```

to

```
Architectures>>
>> Base SDK >>
>> OS X 10.8
```

the app compiles and runs with no further changes.